# CakePHP 3 - using IN...SELECT in a custom finder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have written a [custom finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) method as follows:

```
public function findSubstanceListNotifications(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $date_start = $options['date_start'];
    $date_end = $options['date_end'];
    $list_id = $options['list_id'];

    $list_substances = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('TblListsSubstances')->find()
            ->select('substance_id')->where(['list_id IN' => $list_id])->enableHydration(false);

    if ($list_substances->isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    $query = $this->find()
            ->select(['RevisionSubstances.date', 'RevisionSubstances.comment', 'RevisionSubstances.id', 'Substances.name', 'Substances.app_id'])
            ->where(['substance_id IN' => array_column($list_substances->toArray(), 'substance_id')]);

    $query->where(['RevisionSubstances.date >=' => $date_start, 'RevisionSubstances.date <=' => $date_end]);

    $query->contain('Substances');
    $query->order(['RevisionSubstances.date' => 'DESC', 'Substances.app_id' => 'ASC']);

    $query->enableHydration(false);

    if ($query->isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I'm getting a PHP Fatal Error due to hitting a memory limit when executing this.

The reason, I suspect, is because the `substance_id IN` condition is using an array which has several thousand keys.

Is there an alterantive way to writing this where instead of using `IN` followed by an array, I could write the `SELECT` statement at this point? Similar to a subquery in MySQL.

The SQL for the condition is described by `$list_substances` but essentially is:

```
SELECT substance_id FROM tbl_lists_substances WHERE list_id IN(1,2,3,4);
```

The `IN()` condition above uses ID's pertaining to the logged-in user. However, this array would - at most - have under 20 keys so I don't think there will be any similar memory issues here. But I need to know how to access these at the point of running the subquery too.

CakePHP version is 3.7

I've read about using `newExpr()` in the [docs](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/source-class-Cake.Database.Query.html#1776) but can't see how to inject the `SELECT` statement at this point in a way that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several thousand keys could easily be too much. I'm not sure what your concerns with a subquery are, but it should work just fine, simply pass `$list_substances` as the condition, like:

```php
->where(['substance_id IN' => $list_substances])
```